# Make timestamps have same microsecond length in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I'm not sure whether I missed something on SO, but I haven't found an answer here so far.

I have a pandas dataframe with GPS features (longitude, latitude) and an "eventDate" column with timestamps in `datetime64[ns, UTC]` format. The timestamps have all date information up the second, however, some have nanosecond (6 digits after the decimal point) resolution while others only have seconds (no digits after the decimal point).

An example of the current timestamps would be: `2020-07-31 20:47:48+00:00` vs `2020-07-31 20:47:48.059000+00:00`.

I want to make sure all timestamps have the same length so that those with no trailing zeros will have three zeros or `.001` added to them, while those with six digits after the decimal point will be truncated to only contain 3 digits. So I would want `2020-07-31 20:47:48.059+00:00`.

I have pandas floor and ceil functions, but these do not add the necessary zeroes and do not truncate the sequence after the decimal point.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this in python (eg, using pandas or datetime)?

Comment: Are they definitely all the same datatype?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JonClements I checked the datatypes of the columns and the column is labelled as datetime64[ns, UTC], so they all should be the same datatype

Comment: pandas datetime64 data type has nanosecond precision, no matter if the digits are shown or not. So what exactly is the issue? Do you want to round to microseconds? Do you want the output to be a string with a certain *format*?

Answer (score 1):

By default the pandas indexes will display without trailing zeros when using `datetime64` format. If you want to display it (and posibly export it so) with a particular time format you can use the method [strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html?highlight=index%20strftime#pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime) from DatetimeIndex.

For example you can do the following for your particular case:

```
dataframe.index = dataframe.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```